# Possibility of weaker forms of $P = NP$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Assuming that $P \ne NP$ 
how surprising would it be if a weaker form of $P = NP$ holds?

For example consider the following weaker forms of $P = NP$:

1. $NP \subseteq DTime(2^{O(n^\varepsilon)})$ for some $\varepsilon < 1$.
2. $NP \subseteq DTime(2^{cn})$ for some constant $c < 1$.
3. $NP \not\subseteq DTime(2^{O(n^\varepsilon)})$ for any $\varepsilon < 1$, but 
   there is an efficient algorithm 
   that solves all (or say 99% of) instances that come up in practice.
   E.g. there is some efficiently computable set of inputs and
   an efficient algorithm that solves the promise problem on that set.
   The set contains all "real-world" instances of the problem.
4. $NP \not\subseteq DTime(2^{O(n^\epsilon)})$ for any $\epsilon < 1$, but 
   there is an efficient probabilistic algorithms 
   that is correct with probability $p$ (where $p < 1$).

5-8. 1-4 above with a quantum computer.

How surprising would any of these statements be to theoreticians 
compared to $P = NP$?

Comment: This is quite a broad and open ended question..The conjecture that 1. does not happen is the Exponential Time Hypothesis (ETH). The conjecture that 2. does not happen is the Strong Exponential Time Hypothesis (SETH). If you search with these keywords you will find a lot of information about these two. In 4 if the running time of the algorithm is polynomial for p bounded away from 1/2, then you get NP = BPP $\subset$ P\poly which would be quite a surprise and has many consequences, see the Karp-Lipton theorem.

Comment: @Sasho Nikolov: Interesting. What if in #4, the algorithm is not polynomial for any $p$, but is subexponential for all $0 \le p < 1$?

Comment: @SashoNikolov : ​ ​ ​ "The conjecture that 1. does not happen" _follows from_ ETH, but is certainly not clearly equivalent to ETH. ​ I don't see any way to show an implication in either direction between 2 and SETH, since [reductions to k-SAT can increase size] and [with the "obvious" encoding, even for fixed k, the lengths of k-SAT instances are super-linear in their number of variables]. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @mike3 : ​ ​ ​ ​​If " there is an efficient algorithm that solves" 1% of NP "instances that come up in practice" then: ​ There are no [one-way functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), so there are also no [distributionally one-way functions](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/techreports/tr-89-31.pdf#page=8). ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ (continued …) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (… continued) ​ Furthermore (still in that case), by approximately-uniform inverters and majority-voting and the [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound), "there is an efficient algorithm that solves all" instances of $[\hspace{-0.05 in}$ search problems with constant-round [arguments](http://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F0-387-23483-7_201) $\hspace{-0.05 in}]$ that come up in practice. ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky Demer: How does "1% NP 'instances in practice'" imply that no OWFs? If the algorithm requires, say, a structured input and the OWF was given a pseudo-random input, like the hash off a crypto hash algorithm, then the algorithm would fail to invert the OWF. Looking it up, it seems that OWFs are defined in terms of random input, so an algorithm that solves for structured inputs would be useless for random ones, and thus couldn't they still be OW by the definition given?

Comment: Based on the existence of https, I believe most NP instances "that come up in practice" are cryptographic. ​ (We just do not spend that much effort on trying to actually solve particular such instances, since they're believed to be too hard.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @SashoNikolov Consider converting your comment into an answer.